# Subset a factor by NA levels

Tags: r, subset, missing-data, na, r-factor

I have a factor in R, with an NA level.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), 25, replace=TRUE)
x <- factor(x, exclude = NULL)
> x
 [1] 1    2    2    <NA> 1    <NA> <NA> 2    2    1    1   
[12] 1    <NA> 2    <NA> 2    <NA> <NA> 2    <NA> <NA> 1   
[23] 2    1    1   
Levels: 1 2 <NA>
```

How do I subset that factor by the `<NA>` level? Both methods I tried did not work.

```
> x[is.na(x)]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 2 <NA>
> x[x=='<NA>']
factor(0)
Levels: 1 2 <NA>
```

Comment: This is probably one reason `?factor` has: "Warning: There are some anomalies associated with factors that have ‘NA’ as a level.  It is suggested to use them sparingly, e.g., only for tabulation purposes."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surprising to me that your attempts to do this didn't work, but this seems to:

```
x[is.na(levels(x)[x])]
```

I got there by looking at `str(x)` and seeing that it is the *levels* that are `NA`, not the underlying codes:

```
str(x)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2",NA: 1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1 ...
```

Comment: I think that `x[is.na(as.character(x))]` also works. I was surprised as well at this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up to Ben:

`str(x)` shows you the problem.  Factors are stored as integers internally with a "lookup" of sorts.  So:

```
> all(is.na(x))
[1] FALSE
```

but

```
> any(is.na(levels(x)))
[1] TRUE
```

and as ben showed, to print the actual values of the vector:

```
> levels(x)[x]
 [1] "1" "2" "2" NA  "1" NA  NA  "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" NA  "2" NA  "2" NA  NA  "2" NA  NA       "1" "2" "1" "1"
```

versus

```
> x
 [1] 1    2    2    <NA> 1    <NA> <NA> 2    2    1    1    1    <NA> 2    <NA> 2    <NA> <NA> 2    <NA> <NA> 1    2    1    1
Levels: 1 2 <NA>
```